# Android - Show Back Button from XML

Tags: android-xml, back-button

Before I begin, I want to mention that I've found a million answers showing how to do this **from code**, which involves `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)` from your `Activity`. However, what I have not been able to find is a way how to do it from XML. (I would like to hide as much UI code in the XML files as possible).

One article I did find is [this](https://www.examtray.com/android/how-show-android-toolbar-back-button-programmatically-change-color-shape), which states

> Step 3: Specifying the parent activity name in the AndroidManifest.xml adds the Back-Button arrow
> and Click-action. Tapping on the back-arrow takes us to the Parent
> Activity i.e Home Screen.

which doesn't work for me (the Back Button doesn't appear). I've followed all the steps in the article.

Does anyone know how to do this via xml? Is it even possible?

Comment: Create a custom tool bar through xml by setting `theme` to `noActionBar`, add a imageButton representing back and add a Intent in java. Done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible but still, you have to set the listener in java code. You can create a custom toolbar view and add a button to it. Then create a button in the java file and set the CilckListener.

Or You can use the default toolbar and do `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true) from your Activity`.

We usually make a custom toolbar, suppose you need a search bar in the toolbar then what you will do? So try to make an xml then use `<include>` tag in xml. You can search youtube. Follow the channel CodingInFlow, that guy explains very perfectly. If you don't understand what I am saying then understand the basics first, it will help you learn faster.

Comment: Yeah I already have a toolbar and a `<include>` tag. Basically what you described is what we already have. I was just wondering if I could do better, but looks like calling `setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled` from the Activity is unavoidable. Oh well.

Comment: What does that mean? Code does not have a face and nobody cares about the code. We need a fast and robust application. There should be standard ways of coding so that, in future when we update the application, then it would not be messy. As I suggested you the youtube channel, go to youtube and search "toolbars in android coding in flow" and then see the approaches there. That guy is a experienced developer and a expensive one in 2021.